# React route component not rendering in production build

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Header from './components/header';
import Body from './components/body';
import Archive from './components/archive';
import Settings from './components/settings';

import './assets/css/style.css';

const wrapper = <Router>
      <div>
        <Header/>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Body}/>
        <Route path="/archive" component={Archive}/>
        <Route path="/label/work" component={Settings}/>
        <Route path="/settings" component={Settings}/>
      </div>
</Router>;

render(wrapper, document.getElementById('app'));
```

In above code, Body component is rendered in development mode.
But when I run the same code in production build body component is not rendered.

Output:

Development Mode: Body component rendered

[image]

Production Build: Body component not rendered

[image]

Comment: is there any console errors on production build?

Comment: @BünyaminBennyGenel no console errors

Comment: can you try wrapping wrapper constant with `const wrapper = () => ( // your code here );`

Comment: How are you creating a production build

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I am using webpack.  webpack -p

Comment: can you also add your webpack config

Comment: @BünyaminBennyGenel wrapped my wrapper in () => ( // code ) , but still not working

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri  my webpack config: https://notepad.pw/webpack

Comment: Only Body component won't render? other components are rendering?

Comment: @IdanDagan yes, other components are rendering

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example [in documentation](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/guides/quick-start.md)

Try to replace wrapper with stateless component:

```
const wrapper = () => (
  <Router>
      <div>
        <Header/>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Body}/>
        <Route path="/archive" component={Archive}/>
        <Route path="/label/work" component={Settings}/>
        <Route path="/settings" component={Settings}/>
      </div>
  </Router>
);
```

Comment: what is mean by stateless component?

Comment: Its a functional component (like the one in this answer) that doesn't have any state in its constructor. When you have this case you can then define a component in this manner, and it will only have render function. They are also called *dumb* components.

Comment: @echuve still not rendering.

Comment: @Abhishek how you use development bundle and production bundle? I mean what url do you use to view pages that you share on screenshots?